# Converting Date Column Format to Hours in Talend Open Studio

Tags: talend

I am interested in converting a date column with a string mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss to an hour format using Talend Open Studio. I want the hour of the day from the Date column.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Do you have any pointers to share on that ?

Answer (score 0):

If the String has already been converted to a Date, you could retrieve the hour of the day with formatting in tMap:

```
TalendDate.formatDate("HH",myDate)
```

This will return a String with the hour of the day.

If the String has not been converted, I suggest converting it before - it is always better to have a Date and work on the Date type than doing String processing.

Comment: Hi, tried the TalendDate.formatDate("HH",myDate). I replaced myDate with the date column in my database (ie SoapDate). So my formula looks like

Comment: Looks like? It seems something is missing in the comment.